# How to use one Remote server on multiple projects in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm having a little trouble with PHPStorm and Remote Servers. The great thing about this IDE is that I can specify some settings for global enviroment, or per Project. But I guess it does not include settings for Remote Servers.

For example, consider this scenario. 
I have a remote server on `example.com`. On that server I have 2 folders: `example.com/project1` and `example.com/project2`.

In PHPStorm I created 2 projects with the name of `Project One` and `Project Two`. But I had to create 2 Remote servers with specific root folders. 
For example for `Project One`'s remote server's root folder is specified to `example.com/project` and for `Project Two` the folder `example.com/project2`.

So my questions is, how can I set the one remote server globally, so I could use it for different projects with specific root folders for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main server settings - id, name, type, host, root path, credentials, i.e. all content of Connection tab of server's settings - are stored globally. To be more precise, in //config/options/webServers.xml. So it's available for all projects. Contents of two other tabs of server settings - Mappings and Excluded Paths - is saved per project in .idea/workspace.xml

So, to share 1 server between several projects, make sure to set the server doc root/root URL in Connection tab and specify projects-specific stuff on Mappings tab